# How to create document Id for firestore documents using adminSdk in Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

How to create a document push id for firestore document using Firebase Admin SDK in Firebase cloud function.

I know how to do it in Angular using AngularFire2

```
const bookingId = this.afs.createId();
```

I need to do this thing in my cloud function.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just call [doc()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#doc) with no arguments on a CollectionReference where you would like the document to live.  You can then call [set()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#set) on that returned DocumentReference to create the document.

If you don't even need to create the document and just want the random ID, use the [id](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#id) property on the DocumentReference.

(Realtime Database called these things "push IDs" because you used the `push()` method, but they're just called auto generated IDs in Firestore).

Comment: What if we need access to the id immediately after creating the entry? The response object did not include it for me.

Comment: @DevMike Read the linked documentation for the doc() method.  It returns a DocumentReference which has the ID of the document that will be created after it's set().

Comment: That link https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentReference.html#id is confusing? it references `.doc().add()` but the only options i am seeing as available via the admin SDK are `doc().set` `doc().create` and `doc().update` and all three do not respond with a document reference i am looking here: https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html

Comment: For example, here is the response i am seeing from `doc().set` via the admin SDK: `WriteResult {
  _writeTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1574284714, _nanoseconds: 711962000 } }`

Comment: Ah! Ok i figured it out: i was calling `admin.firestore().collection('collectionName').doc()` when instead i need to create a reference to the collection and then call `add()` on the reference. Apologies, still learning, and got confused.